# java.lang.SecurityException: in android 8 while sending sms

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am facing the issue of security while I am sending SMS from oreo version, it is working properly in another android version.getting an error at below line.

```
 sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null,message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Report 1

```
> java.lang.SecurityException:    at android.os.Parcel.readException
> (Parcel.java:1942)   at android.os.Parcel.readException
> (Parcel.java:1888)   at
> com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber
> (ISms.java:955)   at
> android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal
> (SmsManager.java:372)   at
> android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage (SmsManager.java:355)  
> at com.moba.attendanceapp.RegistrationandVerify.sendSMS
> (RegistrationandVerify.java:172)   at
> com.moba.attendanceapp.RegistrationandVerify.onViewClicked
> (RegistrationandVerify.java:92)   at
> com.moba.attendanceapp.RegistrationandVerify$$ViewInjector$1.doClick
> (RegistrationandVerify$$ViewInjector.java:22)   at
> butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick
> (DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)   at
> android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6267)   at
> android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:24763)   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6548)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
> com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (Zygote.java:240)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: post the logs here

Comment: be sure to add sms permissions

Comment: @Tigo2018 I have edited my question with logs, these logs are from play store, as my application is on play store and I am facing this issue.

Comment: Yeah, @Tigo2018 said, be sure you add SMS permissions in the manifest.  Also make sure you granted it as `RuntimePermissions` in Android Oreo. You can check Settings->Apps->YourApp->Permissions. SMS needs to be activated. If its on the wild already, make sure to check the permission in your app, and tell the user that it doesn't work if he doesn't grant this permission. You can consider to just shutdown your app

Comment: Yes, I have added the permission, other wise it also gives the error in marshmallow.

Comment: already added runtime permissions.

Comment: There is apparently a bug in 8.0, whereby sending messages with `SmsManager` also requires the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. I've not confirmed this on any devices yet, but it does happen on the emulators. Supposedly fixed in 8.1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421412/android-8-requires-read-phone-state-when-calling-smsmanager-sendtextmessage.

Answer (score 0):

Check permission you have added in your menifest file properly.
Secondly check your receiver's intent-filter has added properly.

Answer (score 0):

add these permissions in the `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

and then request them alike:

```
final static int REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION_SMS = 301;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION}, REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION_SMS);
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUESTCODE_PERMISSION_SMS);
}
```

Comment: What is `READ_PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION`?